# Windows 8 smaller Tiles and without title?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

Windows 8 Modern UI is wasting so much space on the screen. Until now I'm still using the old "Quick Launch Bar" on the bottom left with all my programs I use.

But I think it's time to arrange also my icons in the Modern UI. But for me there is just so much space wasted and I need to search all over the monitor to get the icon for my program.

Here two screenshots of first my current situation and then the screenshot of the Windows Modern UI with the programs. My "old" approach is just easy accessible, very very fast (no search on the screen and very small mouse movements) (I do not use a touchscreen and my mouse pointer follows my movements very well).

**Can I make the icons smaller? Remove the titles?** (Because I know the Icon of my programs), Make the Groups "Full Screen"? **Or remove the padding around each tile?**

My current quick launch (the Old UI):

[image: My current quick launch (the Old UI)]

And the wasted space and enormous icons in the ModernUI:
[image: And the wasted space and enormous icons in the ModernUI]

Comment: Right-click under blue space then click on "All Apps" on right bottom corner of your screen. This makes you see smaller icons.

Comment: How exactly is this space wasted? There's nothing else on the Start Screen, the icons are clearly visible, duplicate icons have text to differentiate them, and so on...

Comment: oh yes. I open my applications at moment with a space of about 50px / 250px. The same main functionality will now use my whole screen - so more mouse and eye movements. In addition I always have to go back with my Head because these Icons are at least 2 times the size of all other Desktop components. (Just compare the window close button (the most important button!!!) with any button in the ModernUI. My Resolution is 1680x1050 on a 22".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, tiles have a specific size which you cannot change as they are hardcoded into every Metro program that you install. *Why?* Because of the live tiles, which can't be made smaller.

Answer (score 3):

Alas, no. The only thing you can do at the moment (and it seems you already do) is extentend the maximum number of rows on high resolution screens.

The shaded areas in you screenshot are reserved space and there (at current) is no way to utilize that space.

You can't shrink the tile sizes either (though they are conceptually smaller on higher res displays, the actual dimensions are the same.)

Answer (score 1):

If your monitor has a high enough resolution ([Scott Hanselman's 30" supports this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Windows8ProductivityWhoMovedMyCheeseOhThereItIs.aspx), my 22" 1680x1050 doesn't), you can change a setting to "Show more tiles."  While in the start menu, you can go to settings (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or via the Settings charm) and turn on the more tiles option.

You can also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Scroll to zoom out (each time).